# What's the differences b/w XxxBinding VS XxxBindingImpl? & When and How are they created?

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am trying to understand Android Data Binding.

I noticed that It has a problem with detecting the values each other and I need to `invalidate/restart` and `clean project` quite often. So, I thought I need to find out the solution and solve my curiosity, under the hood.

I figured out that both of them are created when I build the project(compile-time I guess?) if I have set the layout file to data binding format something like this:

```
<layout>
    <data>
    </data>

    <LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

And also, `XxxBindingImpl` inherits `XxxBinding` like this:

```
public class ActivityMainBindingImpl extends ActivityMainBinding  {
    // TODO
}
```

If I have set some `method expression` or `listener expression` in the layout, the class becomes like this:

```
public class ActivityMainBindingImpl extends ActivityMainBinding implements com.example.myapp.generated.callback.OnClickListener.Listener 
{
    // TODO
}
```

And the two kinds of classes are located in `com/example/myapp/databinding`.

I'd like to know the roles of both. And how/why/when are they made for what. And the differences b/w the two.